# Preposition for "Alternative"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I've found out that there are several prepositions for the word **alternative** that all seem to be correct, however, I think there should be a best choice. Do these prepositions affect the meaning in some way?

**For:**

> Ensure that the text **alternative for** CAPTCHA images identifies the type of task and what is required from the user to complete it

**To:**

> This solution is far from perfect, but it is a potential **alternative to** Captcha nonetheless.

**Of:**

> In this tutorial, we discussed an **alternative of** captcha, a plugin called GASP (Growmap Anti spambot Plugin).

Personally, as in my recent article, I do prefer to use "To" as preposition.

Comment: They are all different. Alternative for [entities that may use this alternative, or the category of the alternative]. Alternative to [the main choice]. Alternative of [another choice, not necessarily predominant].

Comment: Yes, "*an* alternative of" .... should be *an alternative to*. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(an+alternative+of)%2C(an+alternative+to)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28an%20alternative%20of%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28an%20alternative%20to%29%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *It's a black-tie event, where...*
>    *...the alternative **for** women is an [LBD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_black_dress).*
>    *...the alternative **to** a black tie is a dark blue one.*
>    *...the alternative **of** a [spinning bow tie](http://www.amazon.co.uk/300/dp/B009NNMSKK) will be rejected by the doormen.*

Comment: @Tim Romano: You're more accommodating than the doormen, obviously! :)